# Class object from view to controller -> NULL

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller

Returns an object from class "Depot" which contains a list with objects from "Gegenstand" class.

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        Depot depotObject = new Depot();
        Gegenstand gegenstandObject = new Gegenstand { Beschreibung = "Door" };
        depotObject.depotItems.Add(gegenstandObject);
        return View(depotObject);
    }
```

The index.cshtml which displays the objects from the list. Now I want to post the object "Gegenstand" to the controller (Comment area)

```
@model MvcApplication2.Models.Depot
<table>
@foreach(MvcApplication2.Models.Gegenstand gegenstand in Model.depotItems)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
                @using (Html.BeginForm("Details", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
                {
                // Want to post "Gegenstand" object to controller
                <input type="submit" value="click" />
                }

        </td>
    </tr>
}
</table>
```

This is the ActionResult for "Details"

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Details(Gegenstand gegenstandObject)
    {
        return View(gegenstandObject);
    }
```

Comment: Why do you do a `POST` request at all to show something? You need a get request instead with an id of the object and fetch it in your details view.

Comment: You just need to generate the controls for each property of `depotItems` in the form (you haven't show the model so hard to say), but why have a separate form foreach `depotItems` as opposed to posting back the collection of `depotItems`? And what is the purpose of the POST method if all you do is return the view (your not saving anything)?

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/758458/Passing-Data-View-to-Controller-Controller-to-View has some View-to-Controller help.

Comment: Start off by thinking of posting HTML input tags, not objects. Which tags do you expect to post? I see no tags except the `input type="submit"` tag.

Comment: A `Details()` method suggests you are displaying details of a `depotItem`. I suspect you really just want an action link that redirects to display details of the `depotItem`, in which case a form is not required (its a GET, not a POST)

Answer (score 2):

You need to build a Gegenstand `object` in your view.

You can achieve this two ways.

Use the `@Html.EditorFor` within MVC in your form and let the framework take care of the model binding.

For instance: `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.YourProperty);`

Or by building the object up and pass a serialized object back up to your `Controller`. You can use `JavaScript` for this and `POST` it back to the controller via an `AJAX` call. For instance.

```
<script>
    function CreateGegenstandObject() {
         var obj = {};
         obj.property = "Your property";  // This should reflect the property in your C# class
         obj.property2 = "Another property"; // Another property that should be reflected

         return obj;
    }

    function sendGegenstandObjectToController() {
          var gegenstandObject = CreateGegenstandObject(); 
          $.ajax({
             url: '@Url.Action("Details")',
             type: "POST",
             data: { gegenstandObject: gegenstandObject.serialize() },
             success: function() { alert('success'); }
          });
    }

</script>
```

You would have to invoke the `sendGegenstandObjectToController` function once the form has been submitted.

Comment: @Donkeyy No. You could do it ASP.Net MVC style by passing the object to the controller on submit

Comment: When I have multiple objects, how can I post only one which i selected?

Comment: @Donkeyy look at Stephen Muecke comment above. Generate the controls for each property.

Comment: @TWhite @Donkeyy - I've added an example using `@Html.EditorFor`

Comment: @Donkeyy Darren has a good answer. He shows you the Razor MVC way with the \@HTML or with a AJAX call the JS way. Either will work. Also, keep in mind the questions Vsevolod and Stephen raise about the POST versus GET call.

Comment: Why should I build a "Gegenstand" object when my list return all of my objects from "Gegenstand" class. I select a row in my table and then I POST the object to the Details() method and this ActionResult return a View with the Gegenstand object. Btw. my english is not the best, but thanks for your help!